# lein ring uberjar -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/Var

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure, ring, compojure-api

Not certain why when I `lein with-profile +live ring uberjar` and then `java -jar` my uberjar, I get this exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/Var`.

`project.clj`:

```
(defproject gn-preview-api "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url  "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]]
  :main gn-preview-api.www.app
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}
             :staging {:aot :all}
             :live    {:aot :all}
             :dev     {:plugins      [[lein-ring "0.9.7"]]
                       :dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]]}})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Leiningen [produces two `.jar` files when you run `lein uberjar`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#uberjar). The one whose filename ends in `...-standalone.jar` is the actual uberjar, which contains Clojure (core). The standalone file can be run simply with `java -jar my_uberjar.jar`. If you run the other (non-uber jar), then Clojure needs to be available in the classpath.

You can view which dependencies are included with each jar file with `jar tf my_uberjar.jar`. The uberjar should contain `clojure/core/...`, `clojure/lang/...`, etc.